# element is not attached to the page document Избитая проблема. Есть идея. Нужно подтверждение и изящное решение

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Как пишут, эта проблема происходит потому, что найденный на странице элемент изменился. Рекомендуют в таких хрупких местах производить повторный поиск элемента. Но в моем случае это не работало, у меня итак перед каждым кликом делался поиск элемента.  Элемент находится, но не кликается, появляется исключение что в заголовке вопроса. 
Появилась такая догадка: а вдруг элемент, который находится еще не полностью был сформирован и поэтому он не кликабельный. Т.е. делаю ПОИСК(элемент нашелся). клик(успешен) ПОиск(элемент нашелся, но наверное надо было повременить с поиском и этот элемент будет не кликабельный) И я стал ставить в sleep поток. После клика подождал, страница прогрузилась и только потом новый поиск. И вроде проблема на 99 процентов случае исчезла. 
Так вот. Можно ли средствами selenium на java задать ожидание перед поиском , такие же которые используются при самом поиске (явные или неявные).
Ну и просьба тем кто разбирается в веб, разъяснить почему так происходит, почему кнопка находится, но не кликабельна, что же там могло не подгрузиться.

Вот тут sendKyes не успевает отработать как начинает отрабатывать Клик. так разве должно быть, Если методы расположены последовательно?

```
element2.sendKeys(elementsOfTheApplication.getCode1C());
        WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));
        element3.click();
```

Comment: а как вы ждете завершения загрузки страницы?

Comment: Я не жду завершения загрузки страницы. Я изначально задаю параметр driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   И теперь загрузка страницы идет и одновременно в течении 10 секунд совершаются попытки найти нужный мне элемент. Т.е. как только элемент загрузится, я его смогу использовать, не дожидаясь загрузки всей страницы.

Comment: Насчет того, что поиск след элемента выполняется не дождавшись вставки sendkeys я был не прав. Ошибка у меня была в том, что на изначальной странице по локатору находился Элемент, который я должен был искать на след странице. Надо просто задать уникальный локатор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного теории не помешает: после поиска элемента селениум присваивает ему уникальный айдишник, который никогда (теоретически, за разумное время) не повторяется. Т.е. вы нашли элемент, потом он по какой-то причине исчез из DOM и заново появился (обновили страницу или javascript отработал) - айдишники будут каждый раз новые. При попытке совершить действие с найденным ранее элементом, селениум ищет его на странице по этому айдишнику, если не находит, то выбрасывается исключение `element is not attached to the page document`.

Если у вас бывает такое, то значит, что есть ошибки в логике теста. Добавлять слипы перед поиском и прочее - костыли, которые в будущем вам аукнутся.  Пообщайтесь с разработчиками, выясните почему элементы могут пропадать без перезагрузки страницы. Ну а далее, когда поймете логику приложения, вооружайтесь явными и неявными ожиданиями и пишите правильный код.

Ну и ответ на ваш вопрос - встроенных механизмов ожидания перед поиском нет, это не будет "изящным" решением. Если элемент пропадает, то, возможно, вы ищете не тот элемент - подумайте над более точным локатором. Если пропадание элемента зашито в логику приложения и у нового элемента абсолютно такой же локатор, то используйте ожидание исчезновения элемента - `stalenessOf(WebElement element)`, а после этого делайте новый поиск.

Если все-таки нет возможности сделать нормально, то такой костыль будет оптимальным: отлавливать исключения `StaleElementReferenceException` и искать заново эелемент (рекурсией, но не забудьте добавить количество попыток, чтобы в бесконечный цикл не уйти)

Comment: Дело в том, что страница всего одна, которая изменяется скриптами. Я не тестирую, а автоматизирую свои действия. И код страницы мне вообще не понятен и с разработчиками никакой связи нет.

Comment: Мне не понятно почему я нашел элемент и в след. же строке хочу по нему кликнуть, но его уже нет.. И так не всегда, через раз получается кликнуть.  Единственное, что приходит в голову, что элементы получают конечный id только в момент,когда скрипты окончательно отработали

Comment: @Turalllb, вполне возможно, что скрипты все время удаляют,добавляют элементы. Тогда вполне возможно, что между поиском и кликом они могут пропасть..

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: suit, да вариант с зацикливанием я и собирался использовать, но прежде хотел понять, в этом ли всё таки проблема. Но точно не поняв, как работает сайт, решил попробовать. Написал и сейчас тестирую. И столкнулся с таким интересным моментом из-за которого у меня зачастую тест(код автоматизации) рушится. А именно: Я нахожу поле для ввода текста, начинаю вводить текст  и по окончанию ввода должен нажать на кнопку поиска. Но! Текст даже не успевает начать вводиться, как кнопка поиска уже нажата..

Comment: suit. Я ошибся. И кажется из-за таких ошибок и рушится код. Например сейчас  я кликал на загрузку страницы. и начинаю поиск элемента, а он как назло существует и на текущей странице и клик по нему выполняется. А на новой уже естественно ничего не выполняется.

Comment: оказывается В джаве можно заюзать StaleTolerantWebDriver decorator, который как раз и решает подобные проблемы, путем повтора поиска элемента, если словили StaleReferenceElementException. Так что, необходимость повторного поиска присутствует.  И у меня пока, что всё работает хорошо, буду завтра на работе тестировать)

Comment: suit, протестировал. Работает достаточно хорошо, но не идеально. Случай такой, что есть пару элементов на которых тест рушится. Например идет поиск элемента и не находит. Жму повтор.  Начинается всё по новой. выход на изначальную страницу и загрузка всех скриптов И снова не находит нужный элемент и на раз 4 он его всё таки находит. Что интересно в момент когда элемент не нашелся, я могу глянуть html страницы и вижу что элемент там есть именно по тому локатору, который и используется.. Странно это. использую я css локаторы. Потом попробую что нибудь еще. Проблема чаще на одном и том же елементе

Comment: @Turalllb попробуй увеличить ожидания. Еще такое может быть (при условии, что локатор верный), если элемент находится в фрейме

Answer (score 0):

UI фреймворки (ReactJS, ExtJS, etc) рендерят свои компоненты в HTML div элементы. Компоненты этих фреймворков обычно имеют свое состояние (state, вероятно привязанный к некоторому store). При изменении этого состояния компонента перегенерирует HTML и заменяет его в HTML div, к которому привязана (привязывается операцией bind/render/renderTo UI фреймворка). При этом предыдущее состояние вполне вероятно что "убивается" и создаётся новое, по новому состоянию, и естветсвенно DOM модель страницы локально/точечно (но не вся) изменяется и у элементов внутри этого HTML div будут новые идентификаторы (пример айдишника - "b35ed7a8-0d99-464d-bf8c-a4ba0dbdba6a")